# Draw part of circle and fill it based on percent

Tags: algorithms, circles

[image]

I need a mathematical algorithm to draw a part of a circle, and fill it ( draw another, smaller part of a circle inside it ) based on a number (percent) from 1 to 100. At the 2. circle the percent is 0, while at 1. its about 30.

Ime certain this can be done with math, but ime beyond stuck :(

Answer (score 1):

Let $r$ be the radius of the inner circle and $R$ be the radius of the outer circle.

Let $t\in [0,100]$ be the percentage you're given.

Then the area you want is obtained with a circle of radius $u$, where
$$
\dfrac{u^2-r^2}{R^2-r^2}=\dfrac{t}{100}
$$
So, you need to solve this equation for $u$.

This equation follows from the expression of the [area of a circular sector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_sector#Area) of radius $u$ and angle $\theta$:
$$
\text{area}=\dfrac{\theta}{2\pi} \pi u^2
$$

Comment: Man if this works and we sell it, i want your PayPall account number!